# how to draw text in center to uiimage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I want to set my text **Sold Out**  to the center in UIimage. but  it not in center .

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {

    let textColor = UIColor.white
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 32)!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        ] as [String : Any]

    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
    // let rect = CGRect(origin: point , size: image.size)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:(image.size.width/2), y: (image.size.height/2)), size: image.size)

    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

caller function

```
 imageViewSoldStatus.image = textToImage(drawText: "Sold out", inImage: UIImage(named:"soldout.png")!, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 5.0, y: 5.0))
```

I have spent of very long time to solve this problem but I could not find any solution.

**Red flag my image**

[image]

above is the screen I obtained. below is the design that I want to achieve.

[image]

**update**

*Marie Dm* answerd used! it is text align center but not image center

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAuu3.png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    //draw image first
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
    
    //text attributes
    let font=UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 32)!
    let text_style=NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    text_style.alignment=NSTextAlignment.center
    let text_color=UIColor.white
    let attributes=[NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:text_style, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:text_color]

    //vertically center (depending on font)
    let text_h=font.lineHeight
    let text_y=(image.size.height-text_h)/2
    let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: text_y, width: image.size.width, height: text_h)
    text.draw(in: text_rect.integral, withAttributes: attributes)
    let result=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}
```

Comment: where i found size ?

Comment: You should probably use image.size. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is your image the red flag or the black rect?

Comment: red flag my image

Comment: Then the width of text_rect should be the width of your image in order to be centered. I update my answer.

Comment: text align center  but not image center . please check my update section

Comment: It is centered horizontally but not vertically. In text_rect, did you put the image height (image.size.height) like for the width?

Comment: Then we need to change the vertical position of text_rect. Try let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: image.size.height/2, width: image.size.width, height: 30)

Comment: What about let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: image.size.height/2-15, width: image.size.width, height: 30)

Comment: if i set let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: image.size.height/2-20, width: image.size.width, height: 30) . then it is appear correct center but is it good solution ?

Comment: Well if you always use this image it's okay but if not you should calculate the height of your text depending on the font. You could use "font.lineHeight" to get the height then center you text vertically. I edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 2):

updated for Swift 5

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
    let font=UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)!
    let text_style=NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    text_style.alignment=NSTextAlignment.center
    let text_color=UIColor.white
    let attributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.font:font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:text_style, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:text_color]
    let text_h=font.lineHeight
    let text_y=(image.size.height-text_h)/2
    let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: text_y, width: image.size.width, height: text_h)
    text.draw(in: text_rect.integral, withAttributes: attributes)
    let result=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marie's answer updated for swift 4

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        let font=UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)!
        let text_style=NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        text_style.alignment=NSTextAlignment.center
        let text_color=UIColor.white
        let attributes=[NSAttributedStringKey.font:font, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle:text_style, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:text_color]
        let text_h=font.lineHeight
        let text_y=(image.size.height-text_h)/2
        let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: text_y, width: image.size.width, height: text_h)
        text.draw(in: text_rect.integral, withAttributes: attributes)
        let result=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result!
    }
```