# SwiftSignatureView adding date, location and name in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, signature

I am using [SwiftSignatureView](https://github.com/alankarmisra/SwiftSignatureView) pod and try to add date, location and a name on the returning `UIImage` from that library.

Does anybody has an idea of how to do that? I looked into the swift file of the library but couldn't find something. How to add these kind of data?

Is there another library for doing something like this?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40627036/7222155] this is the solution, just adding label to uiimage.

Comment: ^`UIImageView`*